# Updating relationship's pivot of a relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel

I've been trying to update a pivot info from a relationship of a relationship with laravel. I've tried two different ways:
1)
    $message->notifications->users->first()->pivot->read = 1;
    $message->save();

2)

```
$message->notifications->users->first()->updateExistingPivot($user, ['read' => 1]);
```

The first one won't work, no error, just does not update. Second one throws error:

```
Call to undefined method App\User::updateExistingPivot();
```

My relationships looks like this in my models:

User.php

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Notification','users_notifications')->withPivot('read')->wherePivot('read',0);
}
```

Notification.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_notifications')->withPivot('read');
}
```

Message.php

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Notification','id');
}
```

I'm stuck here, please help!

Comment: do u want to update one user's all notifications to be read?

Comment: Yes!, that's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you need to update **an existing row** in your pivot table, you may use updateExistingPivot method. This method accepts the pivot record **foreign key** and an array of attributes to update

So if you want to update all notifications of one users. `updateExistingPivot` cannot be used here.

However, you can try to use `newPivotStatement` on `notifications()` relationship, `newPivotStatement` will find all the records in pivot table, so you need to use `where` to filter the records that you want.

```php
$user->notifications()
     ->newPivotStatement()
     ->where('user_id', $user->id)
     ->update(['read' => 1]);
```

Or the efficient way by **Query-Builder**:

```php
\DB::table('users_notifications')
   ->where('user_id', $user_id)
   ->update(['read' => 1]);
```